# why can't linux see my run.sh command?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, path

I have a run.sh in a directory in ubuntu linux 12.04 LTS. I've been changing the Path variable so that it can "see" binaries elsewhere in the directory structure. But I am still getting a command not found even if I specify the full path. I have only basic working knowledge of linux. What is going on? Why can't it see run.sh?

```
memsql@memsql-virtual-machine:~/voltdb/doc/tutorials/helloworld$ sudo /home/memsql/voltdb/doc/tutorials/helloworld/run.sh
sudo: /home/memsql/voltdb/doc/tutorials/helloworld/run.sh: command not found
memsql@memsql-virtual-machine:~/voltdb/doc/tutorials/helloworld$ ls
Client.class  deployment.xml  Insert.class  log     run.sh        Select.java
Client.java   helloworld.sql  Insert.java   README  Select.class  statement-plans
memsql@memsql-virtual-machine:~/voltdb/doc/tutorials/helloworld$ pwd
/home/memsql/voltdb/doc/tutorials/helloworld
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a leading or trailing space in the file name. Can you get to it using tab completion? Could you post the output of `printf "<%s>\n" /home/memsql/voltdb/doc/tutorials/helloworld/*run*`?

Comment: Is `run.sh` executable?

Comment: try `sudo ./home/memsql/voltdb/doc/tutorials/helloworld/run.sh` or `sudo sh /home/memsql/voltdb/doc/tutorials/helloworld/run.sh`. Either should work as long as you have made run.sh executable (`chmod +x run.sh`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make it executable with `chmod a+x run.sh` and then try again.

This will make the file executable.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely what someone else mentioned in that the file isn't executable.  Sometimes, it's something else.

If the shebang (`#!/bin/sh` or equivalent) is incorrect, I've seen the shell report `file not found` or `command not found` even though it *is* there an executable.  When I saw it it was a case of a perl script that had `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` when `perl` was in /usr/bin.

Just figured I'd throw in this other potential cause.